# R find the index of a charactor in dataframe

Tags: r, indexing, character

I have a dataframe with SAT scores for all states in US.

```
'data.frame':   51 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ X2010.rank   : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ state        : chr  "Iowa " "Minnesota " "Wisconsin " "Missouri " ...
 $ reading      : int  603 594 595 593 585 592 585 590 585 580 ...
 $ math         : int  613 607 604 595 605 603 600 595 593 594 ...
 $ writing      : int  582 580 579 580 576 571 577 567 568 559 ...
 $ combined     : int  1798 1781 1778 1768 1766 1766 1762 1752 1746 1733 ...
 $ participation: chr  "3%" "7%" "4%" "4%" ...
```

I need to find the index of a particular state. I tried the which command but its returning integer(0)

```
> which(sat$state=="California")
integer(0)
```

However this command is working for other rows and getting me the index:

```
> which(sat$combined==1781)
[1] 2
```

where am I going wrong. Please help.

Comment: It appears that your states end in a blank space.   Try `which(sat$state=="California ")`       - Note blank at end of California

Comment: `sat$state <- trimws(sat$state)` will clean the white-space up.

Comment: Thank you so much! I figured it out just after posting the question